# Significance of minimumClassCoverage and maximumClassCoverage in https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jacoco/

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jacoco

What is the significance of `minimumClassCoverage` and `maximumClassCoverage` in https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jacoco/

```
jacoco exclusionPattern: '**/generated-sources/**.class',
                            execPattern: '**/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec',
                            inclusionPattern: '**/*.class',
                            sourceExclusionPattern: '**/generated-sources/**.java',
                            changeBuildStatus: true,
                            minimumBranchCoverage: '43',
                            minimumClassCoverage: '80',
                            minimumInstructionCoverage: '54',
                            maximumInstructionCoverage: '80',
                            minimumClassCoverage: '57',
                            maximumClassCoverage: '80',
                            minimumMethodCoverage: '55'
```

Answer (score 0):

### What do the thresholds mean?

These `minimumClassCoverage` and `maximumClassCoverage` are the percentage of class code coverage which define *whether the Jenkins build will green*.

On the same documentation page from your link, you can read.

> And the coverage thresholds allow to configure how much coverage is necessary to make the build green (if changing the build status is enabled).

## How do we understand "class coverage"?

The good question is "what it a *class* coverage?".

We can understand it as one of the following:

- What percentage of lines covered in each particular class?
- How many classes are covered with required instruction/method percentage?
- How many classes of all classes in the project have more than 0 coverage?

### What "class coverage" actually is

The class counter is defined in JaCoCo counters documentation

From https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/counters.html:

> Classes
>
> A class is considered as executed when **at least one of its methods has been executed.** Note that JaCoCo considers constructors as well as static initializers as methods. As Java interface types may contain static initializers such interfaces are also considered as executable classes.

Comment: Does it mean that the specific coverage - class/line/method should be above minimumCoverage and below maximumCoverage ?

Comment: For class coverage, it means that the given percentage of all of classes that you examine for coverage should have at least of one method executed as written above.

Comment: As far as I understand from the documentation, yes, for the green build you have to be within `[minCoverage; maxCoverage]`. Although limiting `maxCoverage` looks really weird. But you can try it yourself on your Jenkins with simple project to cover (something like 1-2 classes in it).

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it but I am facing this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060237/how-to-fix-unstable-builds-when-thresholds-are-met   Moreover when I dont specify maxCoverage, build never fails even if coverage is below minCoverage.